# Target language and Default code page(encoding) in web 8

Tags: web8

I have recently upgraded my SDL Tridion 2013SP1 environment to web8, with latest publishing framework I'm wondering how can we set *Target language* and *Default code page(encoding)* in web 8 environment?

[image]I have searched web 8 documentation couldnt get required required information. Appreciate your inputs!

**Update:** Details about encoding is mentioned in the following [doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-C2F20388-85E4-49AE-82E8-AC9662C96420), Will get the Target language details updated in the web 8 doc sooner.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was fully moved to CD side. From CM side we always use REL as Target Language and UTF-8 as Default Code Page.

Target Language can be configured in cd_deployer_config.xml in your Deployer role:

```
<TCDLEngine>
<Properties>
    <!-- Uncomment any of the following lines to set the target language as a specific language -->
    <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="jsp" />
    <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="dotnet" />
    <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel"/>
</Properties>
```

Default Code page is configured in cd_storage_config.xml of your Discovery service under DeployerCapability role node:

```
<Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://localhost:8084/httpupload">
     <Property Name="undo.enabled" Value="false"/>
     <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
</Role>
```

Comment: In Web8.5 Target Language is configured in the \deployer\config\tcdl-conf.xml