# Custom TCDL tag on page is not processed

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, tcdl

We have situation where we need to implement custom tcdl tag on page level:

In **page dwt** we added this new tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="@@language@@">
<head>

<!-- TEST NEW REL ALTERNATIVE TAGS -->
<rel:RelHelloWorld />
<!-- END OF TEST REL ALTERNATIVE TAGS -->
</head>
```

Java class that should render this tag returns only comment (as you can see in code bellow):

```
public class RelHelloWorld implements TagRenderer
{

@Override
public String doEndTag(Tag arg0, StringBuffer arg1, TransformContext arg2, OutputDocument arg3)
        throws TCDLTransformerException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "<!-- Hello World -->";
}

@Override
public int doStartTag(Tag arg0, StringBuffer arg1, TransformContext arg2, OutputDocument arg3)
        throws TCDLTransformerException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean requiresCodeBlock(TransformContext arg0, OutputDocument arg1, Tag arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

We uploaded jar with this tag into **session service** and in **custom_tcdl_tag_bundle.xml** we register this tag:

```
<Tag Namespace="rel" Name="RelHelloWorld">
        <Handler Class="com.org.tridion.tags.RelHelloWorld" AllowCodeBlock="false" />
</Tag>
```

Then we updated cd_dynamic_conf.xml:

```
<TCDLEngine>
        <Properties>
                <Property Name="tcdl.dotnet.style" Value="controls"/>
                <Property Name="tcdl.jsp.style" Value="tags"/>
                <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel"/>
        </Properties>
        <TagBundle Resource="custom_tcdl_tag_bundle.xml"/>
</TCDLEngine>
```

After restarting of services and republish of page, tag is present:
[image]

Also, we updated **tcdl-conf.xml** in deployer-worker, but result is same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TCDLEngine xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/tcdl-conf.xsd" Version="8.5">
        <Properties>
                <Property Name="tcdl.page.target.language" Value="jsp" />
                <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel" />
        </Properties>
        <TagBundle Resource="com/tridion/smarttarget/tcdl/tagbundle.xml" />
</TCDLEngine>
```

I want to emphasize that this custom tag works **when it is added on dwt of any Dynamic Component Presentation.**

Does anybody know what we are missing? Thanks

Comment: Please provide a bit more details of your web application is it .net or java? Is it using DXA or webform?

Comment: web application is in java

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think it's working for items that are stored on the filesystem. Are your pages stored in the database or on disk?

Comment: Pages are saved on file system and if you set Target language it should work, or we suspect to work
https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14295/target-language-and-default-code-pageencoding-in-web-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this issue is resolved by implementing Apache Freemarker servlet.